# Python: My code only runs on one input and give an index error the rest of the time

Tags: python, python-3.x, index-error

The aim of this code is: The program will use urllib to read the HTML from the data files below, extract the href= vaues from the anchor tags, scan for a tag that is in a particular position relative to the first name in the list, follow that link and repeat the process a number of times and report the last name you find. Start at http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html. Find the link at position 3 (the first name is 1). Follow that link. Repeat this process 4 times. The answer is the last name that you retrieve.

Sample answer:

```
$ python solution.py 
Enter URL: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html
Enter count: 4
Enter position: 3
Retrieving: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Fikret.html
Retrieving: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Montgomery.html
Retrieving: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Mhairade.html
Retrieving: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Butchi.html
Retrieving: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Anayah.html
```

My problem: I seem to only be able to make this program work and get a desired output is if I enter the count at 4 and the position at 0. If the position is more than 0 then I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ass12_2.py", line 21, in <module>
    url= addurllist[pos]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My code so far is :

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


urllist= list()
url= input("Enter URL: ")
count= int(input("Enter count: "))
pos= int(input("Enter position: "))
urllist.append(url)
iter= 0

while iter<= count:
    html= urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup= BeautifulSoup (html, "html.parser")

    addurllist= list()
    tags= soup("a")
    for tag in tags: 
        tag= tag.get("href")
        addurllist.append(tag)
        url= addurllist[pos]
    iter= iter+ 1 
    print (url)
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean `iter<= count` rather than `iter < count`?

Comment: Something tells me you need to _unindent_ this line one level: `url= addurllist[pos]`

Comment: @shadow ahh yeah I actually meant for iter< count. realised after testing with the correction below

Comment: @coldspeed thanks for the heads up! can't believe I missed it wew

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `url = addurlist[pos]` should be indented one to the left. You're calling it right after you append the first element, so it will be out of range for any index over 0.

Comment: Cant believe that I missed that wew. thanks for the help!